# Microsoft SQL Server Management studio, can't find local servers

Tags: sql-server

This is my first time using it, I come from a PHP/MYSQL background and a client is asking me to assist with his MSSQL database and he gave me a file which is the exported database, it doesn't have an extension though.

I downloaded and installed Microsoft SQL Server Management studio but I'm not sure what to do, the tutorials online seem to be able to connect to the local server, on my end when I browse for a Server name I can't find anything under "Local server".

If it helps, the client have informed me that his previous developer (the one who seems to have had a conflict with the client and left) was using the same application with the server type set to "Database engine" and the Authentication set to "Windows Authentication", that's all the information I have.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Operating system file corruption problem may occur this problem that means local server does't visible when (browse for more..) in database engine or connecting the server. I installed sql server in another system. It worked properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed a default instance of SQL Server with Management Studio, use the server name "localhost".  If you only installed SQL Server Management Studio, you will need to at least download SQL Express:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Also, note that if you develop in the latest version of SQL Server, you will not be able to back up and restore to the client's database if the client uses an older version. You will need to ensure all changes are scripted or use dacpacs (which you probably won't use).

Comment: +1 Nice warning about the forward compatibility, you can also enter a period character "." as opposed to "localhost" into the "Server name" dropdown box - less keyboard wear ;)

Comment: I think blank works, too.  I haven't used a local default instance in a while.

Comment: Not in SQL Server 2012 - Doesn't allow empty or blank Server Name, disables "connect" button if you try. Can't remember how the older SSMS work.